# При запуске приложения с использованием библиотеки opencv происходит вылет

Tags: java, android, opencv

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("/storage/sdcard0/pictures/myphoto.jpg"));

Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("/storage/sdcard0/pictures/myphoto.jpg", 1);
```

**ImageView** используя для теста, что картинку по пути видит и отображает
При вызове **imread** приложение начинает запускаться и вылетает, при этом ошибок никаких компилятор не выдает и библиотеки **opencv** нужные подключены.
Вылетает при загрузке просто **opencv**, без вызова каких-либо функций из этой библиотеки
Без нее работает нормально.
Не могу найти в чем причина.